# Issues with websocket: Check didn't succeed by the time a new one was set up

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I am running performance tests using gatling. Gatling is scaling very well for API calls but i find consistent exceptions on websockets. I am not sure if it is a server-side or client-side issue. Ia ms ending websocket heartbeats and waiting for replies from the server using  *check()*.
The code goes like so:

```
...
val sendHeartBeat=repeat(repeatCount){
         .exec(
              ws("Send HeartBeat")
              .sendText("HeartBeatMessage")).exitHereIfFailed    
         .exec(
              ws("Check HeartBeat")
              .check(wsListen.within(3500).until(1))). exitHereIfFailed
         .pause(4000)
}
...
```

The problem arises at the check stage. I run my tests for an hour or so but a few "users" drop off giving **Check didn't succeed by the time a new one was set up** error.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered on Gatling mailing list: Gatling doesn't currently queue messages, just in case you might be setting a check later and would expect to match them. Maybe we'll chance that.

Anyways, you must set your check on the sendText action, so you don't lose messages that might arrive between the sendText and the next exec.

```
.exec(
  ws("Send HeartBeat")
  .sendText("HeartBeatMessage")
  .check(wsListen.within(3500).until(1)))
```

Comment: i tried putting the check before the websocket send, it threw a compile time error.

Comment: You messed up somewhere. See example above.

Comment: Please provide a reproducer